# Im trying to run compass compiler through Grunt but it does not do anything

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs, compass

I'm trying to compile my scss with compass compiler using Grunt, but I get stuck when it runs the task, and it only say: Running `compass:dist`  task and never shows anything else in the console.

This is what I'm getting, and I leave it there for hours and never shows me anything else:

[image]

Versions:

- Ruby: v2.1.6p336
- NPM: v3.10.8
- Sass: v3.4.22
- Compass: v1.0.3
- Grunt: v0.4.5
- Grunt-cli: v0.1.13

Comment: That `[no files]` looks ominous, are you definitely calling the task with all the relevant parameters? (Posting the exact code you're using to start the task might help)

Comment: @DBS this are the params Im using: https://i.imgur.com/vOkFKKR.png

Comment: The thing is that two friends at the office were able to compile with the exact same grunt and compass config, we all have the same package versions of every app installed, thats the weird thing.